# Get first element height in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple element which have same class but different height.
class 'xyz' have just border.
like:

```
<div class='xyz'></div> //1st height=10px
<div class='xyz'></div> //2nd height=5px
<div class='xyz'></div> //3rd height=20px
```

I want to get 1st div height which is height=10px in jQuery.

I am using following for get height

```
$('.xyz').height();
```

but always get 0

Comment: try `.height()`

Comment: `$('.xyz').height` won't return `0`

Answer (score 3):

use `$().css('height')` `$().height()`

`css('height')` returns the exact css i.e. `10px` and `.height()` returns `10`.

```js
console.log($('.xyz').css('height'));
console.log($('.xyz').height());
```

```css
.xyz {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='xyz'></div>
<div class='xyz'></div>
<div class='xyz'></div>
```

Comment: or better just $().height()

Comment: :) ::height() should fallback to clientHeight DOM property when style height is not explicitly set or has relative value

Comment: @RafalR Thanks. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use :eq() selector of jQuery like like:

```
$('div.height:eq(0)').css('height');
```

it will allow to select specific div with index checkout [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)